# Why are my XHR calls waiting for each other to return a response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, session

I have an iframe within a page that is continually polling the server for a session variable that is being actively updated by a "main" XHR.

So basically:

1. Main XHR runs and does its thing, updating a session variable as it runs. Usually takes a while, say more than 10 seconds.
2. While main XHR is running, I poll the server for the same session variable using parallel XHR requests. I'm supposed to update the front-end view whenever I get a response from my polling XHRs.

The problem is that the polling XHRs don't return anything until after the main XHR completes, at which point they are already useless of course. Is this really the expected behavior when dealing with sessions? Something like one session per client connection kind of restriction?

EDIT:

Here's some code snippet. The code is pretty big so I tried to trim it down to the bare essentials. It may have some syntax error as typed here as I just took out the important parts from my source code.

Generate iframe

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click','#proceed_form',function(){
        $('#upload_frame').show(); 
        function set () { 
            $('#upload_frame').attr('src','/productUpload/generateIframe'); 
        }
        setTimeout(set); 
    });
});
```

Iframe

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/assets/js/src/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>

<script>

(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        setInterval(function() 
        {
            $.get("/productController/getProgress", function(data)
            {
                $('#progress_container').fadeIn(100);   //fade in progress bar  
                $('#progress_bar').width(data +"%");    //set width of progress bar based on the $status value (set at the top of this page)
                $('#progress_completed').html(parseInt(data) +"%"); //display the % completed within the progress bar
            }
        )},500);  

    });

})(jQuery);

</script>


<div id="progress_container">
    <div id="progress_bar">
         <div id="progress_completed"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP Application

```
class productUpload extends CI_Controller{ 

    /**
     * Respond to XHR poll request
     *
     */
    public function getUploadedBytesToCloud()
    {
        session_start();
        $uploadedBytes = $_SESSION['bytes_uploaded'];
        echo json_encode(['uploadedBytes' => $uploadedBytes]);
    }

    /**
     * Main controller action
     * Uploads the images of a product to the cloud
     *
     */ 
     public function moveProductImagesToCloud($productId)
     {
          /**
           * Some logic to get the product image directory
           *
           */
           $productPath = '/assets/product/image_dir';
           $directoryMap = directory_map($productPath);
           foreach($directoryMap as $key => $file){
                 /**
                  * Upload file to AWS S3 bucket
                  */ 
                 $this->awsUploader->uploadFile(...);

                 $fileSize = $_SESSION['bytes_uploaded'];
                 $fileSize += filesize(getcwd()."/".$productPath."/".$file);
                 $_SESSION['bytes_uploaded'] = fileSize;
            }
      }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the actual code you're using to make and send the XHR - there's no way to tell what's happening from your description.

Comment: Sounds like you have some kind of race conditions going on if you're trying to update and fetch the same variable across two asynchronous calls.

Comment: @Sacho I added some code snippets.

Comment: @Vidur May be the case but I can't tell as the responses all return at the same time.

Comment: @IntegralWind-up you can probably discern the order in which they come back by logging timestamps to the console - though by definition of race conditions, they'll probably come back in an undefined order. Code snippet to get a timestamp in milliseconds: `(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: I don't really think a race condition is the problem though. As I'm not doing anything in the controller action that is being polled other than starting PHP's native session library and returning my session variable as json data as can be seen in the snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, default session manager (using files) locks the session file when you do session_start and releases it when you do session_write_close (or the scripts ends). Meanwhile other scripts trying to access session, wait to the release. a detailed article [here](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/) or at the manual [session-write-close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: I thought this was the case. Thanks for the confirmation. I'm trying to use the framework's session implementation instead of PHP's native session to no success. But at least I can move on to banging my head  against another wall. Thanks.